# What's the best practice regarding borderline duplicate cases?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Recently there have been a few instances where, although I don't personally believe something is a duplicate, I mark it as a duplicate to bring attention to the relationship between the questions. More specifically, I mark the question as a duplicate because others may feel it is even if I don't. I'm letting democracy decide.

But in some of those instances, my duplicate marking leads to discussions in the comments about whether or not the question is actually a duplicate.

So, my questions:

- Is this discussion in the comments healthy, or perhaps healthier than the (sometimes knee-jerk) decisions made in the review queue? Or does this discussion (that's not *directly* related to the question) just make our SE a bit messier?
- Should I revert to my old practice of simply writing `Related: <link>` in the comments, knowing that this may make it less easy for others to see the possible duplicate in the review queue?

Perhaps this is a silly question—I'm not sure yet!—but it's happened enough recently that I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't think it is a duplicate, but is related or associated with another question, using your old practice or writing Related: Link avoids confusion, so I'd encourage that.

If you are reasonably sure it is a dupe, then please do mark it as such. Sure, there may be discussion, but that's good - community consensus should give us an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me, a relationship between questions isn't enough to mark as a duplicate. If there's a relationship between one question and an existing question, and an answer to that existing question *is also clearly a good and complete answer to the new question* - that's when marking as a duplicate is appropriate, IMO.

> although I don't personally believe something is a duplicate, I mark it as a duplicate to bring attention to the relationship between the questions

I'm not sure that makes sense to me - if you have marked something as a duplicate, then it's a sign that you do believe that it's a duplicate (and the site treats your vote towards the close votes).

Comment: "if you have marked something as a duplicate, then it's a sign that you do believe that it's a duplicate" Perhaps im just overthinking the subsequent "Possible duplicate" remark that then appears in the comments.

Comment: @Richard If I think there's a case that's something is a duplicate but I'm not sure, I tend to follow your idea of simply adding a comment to the effect of `Possibly related: <link>`. An actual  close vote is an active movement towards the closure mechanism being triggered, so when people see a vote, they will usually assume that the voter thinks the question should be closed.

Comment: Which then begins the ever-present knee-jerk close vote that tends to happen on every SE, which is what I want to stay away from!

Comment: @Richard yes, unfortunately there can be quite a noticeable "mob closing in" effect sometimes! I do think the wider issue of duplicates is a very pertinent one on music.SE BTW - due to the nature of the topic, a great many questions are partial duplicates.